# boost library cross compilation for arm

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, arm, angstrom-linux

I am trying to compile boost v1.64 for arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++

For that I am following below steps:

1) ./bootstrap.sh

2) Modified the project-config.jam by replacing the line with "using gcc" by:

using gcc : arm : /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;

3) ./bjam install toolset=gcc-arm --prefix=. --with-date_time --with-system --with-random

Error is as following:

Performing configuration checks

```
- 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : yes (cached)
- symlinks supported       : yes (cached)
```

Component configuration:

```
- atomic                   : not building
- chrono                   : not building
- container                : not building
- context                  : not building
- coroutine                : not building
- coroutine2               : not building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : not building
- fiber                    : not building
- filesystem               : not building
- graph                    : not building
- graph_parallel           : not building
- iostreams                : not building
- locale                   : not building
- log                      : not building
- math                     : not building
- metaparse                : not building
- mpi                      : not building
- program_options          : not building
- python                   : not building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : not building
- serialization            : not building
- signals                  : not building
- system                   : building
- test                     : not building
- thread                   : not building
- timer                    : not building
- type_erasure             : not building
- wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 26996 targets...
...updating 44 targets...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o
In file included from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp:14:0:
./boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp:16:21: fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
 #include <stdexcept>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.so for lack of <plib>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                 from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o" "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>error_code.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_system.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_system.so for lack of <plib>libboost_system.so.1.64.0...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/random_device.o
In file included from libs/random/src/random_device.cpp:15:0:
./boost/random/random_device.hpp:21:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_RANDOM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/random_device.o" "libs/random/src/random_device.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/random_device.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_random.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>random_device.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_random.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_random.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_random.so for lack of <plib>libboost_random.so.1.64.0...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o
In file included from 

    libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp:14:0:
    ./boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp:16:21: fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
     #include <stdexcept>
                         ^
    compilation terminated.

        "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp"

    ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
    ...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a...
    gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o
    In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                     from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                     from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                     from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
    ./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
     #include <cstddef>
                       ^
    compilation terminated.

        "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o" "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp"

    ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>error_code.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>error_code.o...
    ...skipped <plib>libboost_system.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a...
    common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static
    common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi
    gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/random_device.o
    In file included from libs/random/src/random_device.cpp:15:0:
    ./boost/random/random_device.hpp:21:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
     #include <string>
                      ^
    compilation terminated.

        "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/random_device.o" "libs/random/src/random_device.cpp"

    ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/random_device.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>random_device.o...
    ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>random_device.o...
    ...skipped <plib>libboost_random.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a...
    ...failed updating 10 targets...
    ...skipped 18 targets...
    ...updated 16 targets...
```

Please help me with the issue.
Thanks

**Update**
Following is log after adding d+2

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp"

In file included from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp:14:0:
./boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp:16:21: fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
 #include <stdexcept>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.so for lack of <plib>libboost_date_time.so.1.64.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o" "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                 from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>error_code.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_system.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_system.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_system.so for lack of <plib>libboost_system.so.1.64.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/random_device.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_RANDOM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/random_device.o" "libs/random/src/random_device.cpp"

In file included from libs/random/src/random_device.cpp:15:0:
./boost/random/random_device.hpp:21:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_random.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>random_device.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_random.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_random.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <plib>libboost_random.so for lack of <plib>libboost_random.so.1.64.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:12:0,
                 from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
 #include <exception>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp"

In file included from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp:14:0:
./boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp:16:21: fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
 #include <stdexcept>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>gregorian/greg_month.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_date_time.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_date_time.a...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o" "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp"

In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                 from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>error_code.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>error_code.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_system.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_system.a...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/random_device.o

    "/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/random_device.o" "libs/random/src/random_device.cpp"

In file included from libs/random/src/random_device.cpp:15:0:
./boost/random/random_device.hpp:21:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>random_device.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>random_device.o...
...skipped <plib>libboost_random.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/random/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_random.a...
...failed updating 10 targets...
```

Comment: can you add the command line option `-d+2` to the bjam command? perhaps it will help to see the actual commands executed.

Comment: I have updated log after your suggestion.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Are you sure you've compiled and installed the standard libraries in the correct place for this compiler build?

Comment: Which are the standard libraries needs to be installed for cross compilation?

Comment: When you build gcc you also need to build the standard library for it.

Comment: Yes. Path for standard libraries is: /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/armv7at2hf-vfp-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib

Comment: It's on a different path then? You'll want a -isysroot option to point the compiler at he standard libraries, no?

Comment: I think, I am facing issue because of sysroot path is not set. As output of arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ -print-sysroot is /not/exist This is common with yocto. So I am trying to find how to set sysroot path.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: I tried with ./bjam install toolset=gcc-arm --sysroot=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/armv7at2hf-vfp-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi --prefix=. --with-date_time --with-system --with-random   But getting same error

Answer (score 0):

[boost](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/53711/) can be build using OpenEmbedded. There is no need to compile boost outside of OpenEmbedded and it also defeats the very purpose of using a build system like OpenEmbedded in the first place. Adding the below

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"
```

to local.conf file should add boost to the image and also to the SDK if the concerned SDK is generated.